# tf.records with TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: tensorflow

```
for i in range(0,len(ntest)):
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
          feature={
            'X': tf.train.Feature(
                float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[np.zeros((10,10))])),
            'uttid': tf.train.Feature(
                bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[ntest[i]])),
            'Y': tf.train.Feature(
                bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[TestTarget[i].eval(session=sess).tostring()]))}))
    serialized = example.SerializeToString()
    writer.write(serialized)
```

The error is :TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars .

```
'X': tf.train.Feature(
                    float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[np.zeros((10,10))]))
```

I can not figure this out

Comment: I have solved it ,value just accept 1-d np.ndarray ,so I just need reshape the value in (None,)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I have solved it ,the value of serial data just accepts 1-d np.ndarray ,so I just need reshape the value in 1d array

Comment: btw you can convert 2d image into 1d and then convert it back if you know the image dimensions, GL